# MYSQL PHP - Get max numer from table then print first column in row

Tags: php, mysql

I have good code for list highest number, but idk how to print first id from row.

```
list($max) = mysql_fetch_row($rowSQL);
```

Example table:

```
Id | xxx | Number
1.   xxx | 20
2.   xxx | 42
3.   xxx | 5
```

I want print Id 2 because have highest number.

Im using include so i mustnt write db name etc.

(I want print name from id 2)

Asking from phone.

Comment: Please read "How do I ask a good question?": http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to find the highest number and then print out the data that row has? If that's the case:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1;
```

That means you most certainly have the highest number, so you can just echo out the elements the query produces. :)

Comment: Found better option

`$honor = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(honor) AS max FROM guilds");
list($max) = mysql_fetch_row($honor);`

Comment: That's the same as mine. Yours doesn't get the extra data tho.